# Can you write images on tkinter root window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there was a way to print text on a tkinter root window, if it is possible please let me know how.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_text-method)?

Comment: Your title is about image, but your question is about text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'Root window' u mean window = Tk():

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.geometry("800x600")

# This line should give you a text line in the top-left of the window
Label(window,text = "Enter your text here").grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```